# insert duplicate keys to hash map

Tags: java

I have created hash map and when I debug it I saw that I have duplicte keys.
I didnt override the `hashCode()` & `equals(Object obj)` in the key - `Object1`
and i wonder how will it affect the performance of the map search?

```
private HashMap<Object1,Object2> map = new HashMap<Object1,Object2>();
```

Comment: If you have duplicate keys... remove one?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to build a road to Rome, but I've built one going somewhere else accidentally – will that take me longer or not?

Comment: i dont think you should have dupliate keys, if you allow for that you might get wrong entry from your map

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys. You may *think* you do, but you don't.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to have duplicate keys in a Map, you have different keys that "appear" the same (Maybe based on their `toString()`? )because you have not overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()`, but in reality the keys are different.

This means that in order to get *all* values from your Map you need to keep *every* key you created and store it somewhere, which to me defeats the purpose of the Map.

Summary:

Override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, then put your key/value pairs into the Map.

Comment: I would say they don't "appear" the same, the OP just *thinks* they're duplicates.

Comment: @BrianRoach Well I can certainly see why they *think* they are the same, `MyObject("A", "B") != MyObject("A", "B")` if you are only using `Object.equals()`, but their `toString()` calls probably look identical. I added a line in response to your comment.

Comment: What I meant was that they only "appeared" to be the same to the OP; the `HashMap` certainly doesn't think they look alike at all ;) The underlying problem here is that the OP doesn't understand that his `HashMap` uses the same criteria for Object comparison as anything else which your answer covers.

Answer (score 0):

It won't really give you bad performances (more the opposite) but it will prevent your objects from being seen as duplicate.

If you want each instance to be seen as a different key, don't override the equals and hashCode methods. But that means you'll need exactly the same instance to retrieve your value in the map.

If you want to retrieve the value with a different instance (for example with the same id), then you need to override the methods.

But the problem isn't really a performance one.

Answer (score 0):

How can you have duplicate keys? You didn't override `equals()` neither `hashcode()` so you cannot say "duplicated objects", because that's exactly the purpose of theses methods. You probably debug and saw different values, but for the JVM they are not equals based on the default `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashcode()` (well actually the closest superclass)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have **duplicate keys** but you can have **duplicate values**. Might be you got confused with the key and value.